# Calling multiple models in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am having trouble running more than one model in my controller.

The first model is encryption then the second model is insertion.

```
public function addStore()
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $gpsAddress = $_POST['gps_address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $status = 1;

    $this->load->model('EncryptionModel');
    $password = $this->EncryptionModel->encryptPassword($password);

    $this->load->model('StoresModel');
    $this->StoresModel->addStore($name, $address, $gpsAddress, $phone, $email, $password, $status);
}
```

The following is the error

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function addStore() on a non-object in \application\controllers\stores.php

This does not occur when the encryption model call is taken out.

Encryption Model as requested

```
class EncryptionModel extends CI_Controller {

public function encryptPassword($password)
{
    $options = ['cost' => 12];
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
    return $password;
}
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your EncryptionModel. Post the code for EncryptionModel

Comment: Added for you to see

Comment: Why is your model extending CI_Controller?

Comment: Thanks Tim all is good now much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be...

```
class EncryptionModel extends CI_Model {
```

Note `CI_Model` in place of where you had `CI_Controller`.

---

Also see the [CodeIgniter class naming recommendations](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#class_and_method_naming) regarding upper and lower case best practices...

> *"Class names should always start with an uppercase letter. **Multiple words should be separated with an underscore, and not CamelCased**. All other class methods should be entirely lowercased and named to clearly indicate their function, preferably including a verb. Try to avoid overly long and verbose names."*

> **INCORRECT**:
> class superclass
> class SuperClass
>
> **CORRECT**:
> class Super_class
>
> ```
> class Super_class {
>     function __construct()
>     {
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Encryption Model was extending CI_Controller where it should be extending CI_Model

Thanks everyone.